# Accessing dropdown value from MasterPage in Content Page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, dropdown, content-pages

I have master page and content page, on the master page, i have a dropdown which list downs currencies, and based on selection of the value from dropdown, the price-value on the content page should get updated, but since the content page_load event gets fired first

I do not get the latest currency selected from the currency dropdown, because of which, i have to refresh the page again in order to get the latest values. I tried the cookie way, on the first page load, i set the default currency in the cookie, and on the selectedindexchange event i update the value in the cookie, based on the currency selected.

However since first content pages' page_load event gets fired, i am not able to accomplish the desired results.

Does anyone has any ideas of accessing the latest selectedindexchange event data on the page load, without reload the page, or without reloading the page_load event of the content page.

Comment: How moving your code to Page_PreRender?

Comment: @hardkoded ok, so as per your suggestion, i placed the content pages page_load content into page_prerender function, but it's still the same, on selecting the currency dropdown, does not effects the values on the content page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindControl on the DropDownList on the Master from the page and get the correct value. You don't need to use PreRender. I'm not sure how you are getting the value at the moment but the below code works.

```
DropDownList ddl = Master.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: if i do this, it would give me the older value, because the content page load executes first and the dropdowns selectedindexchange event, so by the time the dropdowns selectedindexchange events gets called, the content page would be already loaded.

Comment: No it does not. The correct value is already available. Did you try it? And if it does not work you are probably setting the old value somewhere. I tested this with a Master and worked just fine.